# ListView last item aligned to the bottom

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to have last item of the listView aligned on the bottom.
In case there are 1 to several items on the list, there should be an empty space between last item and second to last item.
In case there are many items (they do not fit in the list, scroll is shown), the list should behave normally.
I tried to make it so that when list consists of some small hardcoded number (6) of items (or less), last item is separate view aligned to the bottom of the parent of the listView. When there are more items, I set visibility of this view to GONE and added same view to the listView. It was working fine, but not for all devices. Some fit 6 items, but others fit 7.

Is there any way to align last item to the bottom of the listView (so the listView has always the same height as its parent)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to implement this will be just to add your last element as footer using [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: this doesn't create a gap between item views and footer views; it's only so you can have additional views unmanaged by adapter on the bottom of the list, but if the list contains only few item, list is still has the height of sum of all children and dividers

Comment: If you set the list height to "fill_parent".

Comment: Still it doesn't work. ListView seems to ignore fill_parent and instead uses it's children to calculate its height.